# Plot x,y,z values from columns of different files in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

A MATLAB script has given me as output three matrices `X,Y,Z` that are saved in three different files `x.dat, y.dat, z.dat`. They are all equal in size.

I want to do a 3d plot of columns of `x.dat` vs. columns of `y.dat` vs columns of `z.dat` i.e plot column-wise from the three files. How can this be achieved?

Edit: I'm not sure why this question was not understood but I will re-explain just the same. The x,y,z values are in three different files arranged in columns (say 10 columns in each file) and I wanted to plot them. Using the paste command first and then following Karl's answer I was able to do that.

Comment: Is it worth using the files for x and y? Based on your other question it could be enough to use `splot "z.dat" matrix`

Comment: It was hard to get that you actually want e.g. ten plots. One with data from columns #1, then #2, etc. Mentioning that this is a 4D dataset would've helped. Then it also makes starts making sense to split it over three files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unix's `paste` command, or combine the data in a spreadsheet, or have matlab print them all in one file.

```
system("paste x.dat y.dat > xy.dat") # unixoid "paste" command
plot "xy.dat" using 2:4
```

I understand your files look like following

```
#x.dat             #y.dat             #z.dat
xa1 xb1 xc1 ..     ya1 yb1 yc1 ..     za1 zb1 zc1 ..
xa2 xb2 xc2 ..     ya2 yb2 yc2 ..     za2 zb2 zc2 ..
xa3 xb3 xc3 ..     ya3 yb3 yc3 ..     za3 zb3 zc3 ..
xa4 xb4 xc4 ..     ya4 yb4 yc4 ..     za3 zb4 zc4 ..
.                  .                  .
.                  .                  .
```

If you want to make  `n` xyz plots of a,b,c,..., you can iterate through the combined file like this:

```
splot for [i=1:n] "xyz.dat" using i:n+i:2*n+i
```

Comment: Can you explain why it should be 2:4 ? If x.dat and y.dat has say 10 columns each and the paste command joins them together, how would I specify the column numbers? x values would be from columns 1 to 10 and y values would be from columns 11 to 20.

Comment: Indeed it would be but I am at a loss as how to explain it more clearly. I wanted to plot from three different files using their columns where the first file contains x values etc. Based on Raphael's and your answers I could do that.

Comment: There aren't 10 columns. I said "has say 10 columns" to exemplify it. My apologies just the same for not stating this assumption in the question. I thought a general answer existed independent of the number of columns. However, I have now updated my question.

Comment: I should have provided that file format. I'm sorry that I did not. Yes, splot for [i=1:n] "xyz.dat" using i:n+i:2*n+i is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot cannot handle this, either change your matlab script to produce one file or use the unix `paste` command:

```
splot '<paste x.dat y.dat z.dat' u 1:2:3
```

Comment: u 1:2:3 will not work if x.dat y.dat and z.dat have 10 columns each. How would I modify it? If x.dat, y.dat and z.dat have say 10 columns each and the paste command joins them together, x values would be from columns 1 to 10 and y values would be from columns 11 to 20 and z from 21 to 30

Comment: @user1420 If you don't know which column you want, how should we?

Comment: @user1420 I suggest that you edit your question to be more precise, I dont understand what you want to achive. If A,B and C are matrices, I don't understand what kind of plot you want to achieve

Comment: @Karl, I'm asking how I would modify u 1:2:3. I know which columns to use. I just don't know how to specify it in gnuplot code. I need something like 
u [1:10]:[11:20]:[21:30]